# Calling the header file in the parent folder

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I'm doing some experiments to learn **CMake**. So the commands stay in my mind. I created a project to test what I just learned. However, I have a problem.

The structure of my project is as follows:

```bash
├── bin
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── Configuration
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── Test
    │   │   └── TestConfiguration.h
    ├── Array
    │   └── Array.h
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Test2
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── Test2.cpp
    │   ├── Test2.h
    │   └── Test2-1.h
    ├── Main
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── Config.h
    │   └── Main.h
    ├── Test3
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── Time.h
    │   ├── Timer 
    │   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   │   ├── Iterate.h
    │   │   ├── Run.h
    │   │   ├── Serial.cmpl.cpp
    │   │   └── Serial.h
    │   ├── Smart.h
    │   ├── Counting.h
    │   ├── Mute.h
    │   └── MainTest.h
    └── Utilities
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── Inform.h
        ├── Settings.h
        ├── Print.h
        └── Const.h
```

But I didn't understand how I should make these `CMakeLists.txt` files. For example, the file `src/Utilities/Inform.h` uses the following header:

```cpp
// src/Utilities/Inform.h
#include "Main/Config.h"
```

I've tried everything I've seen on the internet and stackoverflow to edit the `src/Utilities/CMakeLists.txt`  file. But no matter what I do, it never sees the `Main/Config.h` file. I just need to do something like `../../Main/Config.h`.

The same problem applies to other folders. What I want to learn here is to be able to navigate and call all files in the project with CMakeLists.txt. While doing this, I tried many of the following parameters:

```c
add_library
target_include_directories
target_link_libraries
link_directories
link_libraries
```

I think there's something I'm missing or misunderstood. I would be glad if you help me in this regard. If you tell me how to edit the src/Utilities/CMakeLists.txt file, I will try to fill the others accordingly.

Additionally, there is something I'm curious about. Do I also need to edit the `src/CMakeLists.txt` file? Or is it enough if I just edit for example `src/Utilities/CMakeLists.txt`?

Also, I don't know if it will be needed additionally, but I'm using `cmake version 3.16.3`. My development environment is an `x86_64 20.04.1 Ubuntu-based Elementary OS`.

I've read the official documentation for CMake 3.16 and the answers from fellow developers on StackOverFlow. I want to use the header file in the parent folder in a header in subdirectories. But many ways I've tried are wrong. There is always an error in the include path I entered. I want to learn from experienced developers what I did wrong.

Comment: I don't undferstand why you have CMakeLists.txt files in folders that only have header files.  The only reason I can think of is if you want to generate header files at build time.  Generally speaking, CMakeLists.txt should only be found in folders that will generate a compiled output.

Comment: Ah so there is no need to have CMakeLists.txt in every folder? Because I read on a blog something like: "The CMakeLists files are looking for each other so they must be in every folder." So this is wrong.

Comment: You may have misread the comment or it's wrong. In a `CMakelists.txt` if you have an add_subdirectory( mychildfoldername) then the `mychildfoldername` folder needs to have a CMakeLists.txt however you don't want to put add_subdirectory for folders you don't want to have a CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Well I guess I got it. There's no point in your CMake if there's nothing to produce output. Thank you!!!

Comment: I usually have a hierarchy of folders having CMakeLists.txt but not down to the src or include level. There my be some intermediate folder containing a CMakeLists.txt like a Utilities folder off the root of the project and inside that Utilities folder are several folders each representing an executable having a separate CMakeLists.txt for each. I have done this since I started with CMake at work in 2008.

Comment: you could make an [interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) for your header only folders but its probably overkill

Comment: so how do I call header from a place where I only have header folders? Is it wrong to use something like "../../src/Main./Config.h"?

Comment: I use that method sometimes with my CMake based projects at work (which contain several hundred source files and several hundred thousand lines of code) in some cases. With that said I have seen several posts on users who don't like this approach. You could also set target_include_directories() to add the folder containing the target.

Comment: Imho it's a bad choice to put the header at `src/Main/Config.h`, if you want to refer to it as `#include "Main/Config.h"`, since this removes the possibility of only providing headers in `Main` and not those in e.g. `Test2`. It would be better to put it at `src/Main/include/Main/Config.h` and include `add_library(Main INTERFACE) target_include_directories(Main INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` in `src/Main/CMakeLists.txt` and simply provide access to those headers by using `target_link_library(... Main)`